# I want to load a page but this condition is not working

Tags: jquery, html

```
//this is the jquery codition
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    if($("#sel").change.val =="info"){ 
        $("#in").load("insert.info");
    }
});



// This is the select option
<select id="sel">
    <option value="info">About Us</option> 
    <option>Contact Us</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your jQuery to:

```
$("#sel").change(function(){
    if($(this).val() =="info"){ 
        $("#in").load("insert.info");
    }
})
```

Comment: // i erase my jquery then i copy yours its not working then i try to put document.ready still not working

Comment: What part of it isn't working? What errors do you get? What type of content is insert.info?

Comment: the if condition is not working sorry its  not insert.info. It is insertinfo.php